# Struggling to replace SPINNER with BUTTONS populated from database

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter, android-button, android-adapterview

Trying to replace spinner with buttons dynamically populated from database.
Normally spinner use array adapter and built-in List Item Layouts "android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item"etc.

How should it be modified if instead of spinner you want to populate buttons?

Should I replace layouts for spinner in my in loadDifficulties() method with layouts for buttons?

**HERE HOW IT  WORKED WITH SPINNER**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting_screen);
spinnerDifficulty = findViewById(R.id.spinner_quizlist);
loadDifficulties();
Button startTest = findViewById(R.id.start_test);
startTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        startQuiz();
    }
});
}
private void startQuiz() {
ListQuiz selectedLevel = (ListQuiz) spinnerDifficulty.getSelectedItem();
int LevelListID = selectedLevel.getId();
String quizListName = selectedLevel.getName();
Intent intent = new Intent(StartingScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DIFFICULTY_ID, LevelListID);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DIFFICULTY_NAME, quizListName);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_QUIZ);
}
private void loadDifficulties(){
QuizDbHelper dbHelper = QuizDbHelper.getInstance(this);
List<ListQuiz> LevelList = dbHelper.getAllListQuiz();
ArrayAdapter<ListQuiz> adapterLevelList = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, LevelList);    adapterLevelList.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinnerDifficulty.setAdapter(adapterLevelList);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Briefly

- Created LinearLayout for buttons.
- I didn't need to use ArrayAdapter in the loadDifficulties anymore.
- Added all needed parameters to startQuiz() (in my case int & String) simplifying method to Intents only.

  ```
  private ArrayAdapter <ListQuiz> adapter;
  private  Button autobutton;
  public int categorySize;
  private List<ListQuiz> categoryName;
  private LinearLayout QuizListLayout;
  private  Button levelButton;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting_screen);
  autobutton = findViewById(R.id.autobutton);
  loadDifficulties();

  QuizListLayout = findViewById(R.id.layoutForButtons);
  for(int i=0; i<categorySize;i++){

      levelButton =new Button(this);
      levelButton.setText("" + categoryName.get(i));
      levelButton.setId(i);
      final int index = i;
      levelButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
      levelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              startQuiz(v.getId(), categoryName.get(index).toString());
          }
      });
      QuizListLayout.addView(levelButton);
  }
  }


  private void startQuiz(int LevelListID, String quizListName) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(StartingScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DIFFICULTY_ID, LevelListID);
  intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DIFFICULTY_NAME, quizListName);
  startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_QUIZ);
  }

  private void loadDifficulties(){
  QuizDbHelper dbHelper = QuizDbHelper.getInstance(this);
  List<ListQuiz> LevelList = dbHelper.getAllListQuiz();
  categorySize = dbHelper.getAllListQuiz().size(); 
  categoryName = dbHelper.getAllListQuiz();
  ```

buttonlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/layoutForButtons">
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onCreate(){    
LinearLayout listOrders = findViewById(R.id.listOrders);
    for (int i = 0; i < listForShowing.size(); i++){
        String text = listForShowing.get(i);
        listOrders.addView(createButton(text));
    }
listOrders.requestLayout();
}

public Button createButton(String text){
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
Button button = inflater.inflate(R.layout.button, null);
button.setText(text);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Just can't realise how that listForShowing should look like, in my case that information comes from ListQuiz to ArrayAdapter in loadDifficulties method. BTW I'm from Stavropol as well.

Comment: Cool.. 
listForShowing can be any source of data like List<T> or simple array[]. Just for loop to get new text for creating button